# How to create multipurpose WP theme folder structure?

Tags: wordpress, themes

We are developing Multipurpose theme to sell on ThemeForest. However, we got stuck in folder structure and data import.

Folder structure & Data Import detail brief: 
We have 10+ Categories. Each category have different pages, different style, different menu, different images.

Query:
 1. What will be the folder structure for each category?
 2. Where we have to store CSS, JS, Fonts etc separately for each category?
 3. How we can make the data importer for each category?

Regards,
Ankit

Answer (score 0):

You have somehow identify the category ... so you have to tell the theme in the backend that cat id `123` has the template `xyz`. I recommend using [theme options with the customizer](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API) to create that relations (because the IDs may change in each installation).

Then you can say in the `category.php`:

```
if( is_category( $my_theme_options_cat_for_template_xyz ) ):
    include_once get_template_directory()."/includes/categories/xyz.php";
elseif( ... )
    ...
else:
    include_once get_template_directory()."/includes/categories/default.php";
endif;
```

These conditions should work also when you enqueuing your scripts and styles.